# Свободное управление камерой мышью

Tags: c++, directx

Начал реализовывать потихоньку камеру - вроде получилось - но управлять могу только клавиатурой, хотелось бы сделать управление мышкой, как в играх, где камера с видом от первого лица, собственно код подсмотрел в чужой недоделанной статье, получилось следующие - камера вроде работает нормально - но вектор правого угла камеры и вектор верхнего угла камеры постоянно куда - то не в ту сторону трансформируются и получается наклон по координате Y, помогите исправить это:

```
float vx = 0.0f, vy = 0.0f, vz = 1.0f;
//Получаем координаты мыши клиентского окна
vx = mpos(hwnd_).x * (float) 0.01;
vy = mpos(hwnd_).y * (float) 0.01;

float vr = (float)(sqrt(pow(vx, 2) + pow(vy, 2) + pow(vz, 2)));

float vtx = (float)(sin(vx) * sin(vy)) * vr;
float vty = (float)(cos(vy)) * vr;
float vtz = (float)(sin(vy) * cos(vx)) * vr;

lookTargetPostion_ = D3DXVECTOR3(vtx, vty, vtz);    

if (pIDirect3DDevice9_->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &getCameraSettings()) != D3D_OK) {

    msg_er_full;
}
```

На всякий случай

```
D3DXMATRIX Camera::getCameraSettings()
{
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&lookTargetPostion_, &lookTargetPostion_);

    D3DXVec3Cross(&upPosition_, &lookTargetPostion_, &rightPositition_);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&upPosition_, &upPosition_);

    D3DXVec3Cross(&rightPositition_, &upPosition_, &lookTargetPostion_);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&rightPositition_, &rightPositition_);

    (cameraSettings_)(0, 0) = rightPositition_.x; (cameraSettings_)(0, 1) = upPosition_.x; (cameraSettings_)(0, 2) = lookTargetPostion_.x; (cameraSettings_)(0, 3) = 0.0f;
    (cameraSettings_)(1, 0) = rightPositition_.y; (cameraSettings_)(1, 1) = upPosition_.y; (cameraSettings_)(1, 2) = lookTargetPostion_.y; (cameraSettings_)(1, 3) = 0.0f;
    (cameraSettings_)(2, 0) = rightPositition_.z; (cameraSettings_)(2, 1) = upPosition_.z; (cameraSettings_)(2, 2) = lookTargetPostion_.z; (cameraSettings_)(2, 3) = 0.0f;
    (cameraSettings_)(3, 0) = -D3DXVec3Dot(&rightPositition_, &cameraPosition_); (cameraSettings_)(3, 1) = -D3DXVec3Dot(&upPosition_, &cameraPosition_); (cameraSettings_)(3, 2) = -D3DXVec3Dot(&lookTargetPostion_, &cameraPosition_); (cameraSettings_)(3, 3) = 1.0f;

    return cameraSettings_;
}
```

Я так понял, что мне нужно трансформировать вектор правого края камеры и верхнего, подскажите как сделать правильно

Comment: Выглядит, как будто вы матрицу руками конструируете. А почему не используете простое перемножение матриц взгляда и смещения?

Comment: мне так понятнее что и как расчитывается изнутри

Comment: Учитесь выносить код в подпроцедуры

Comment: Причем здесь процедуры? Я прошу помочь с расчетами

Comment: Разделив код на процедуры, вы сможете его протестировать по раздельности (отдельно правильность получения матрицы вращения, отдельно правильность получения матрицы переноса, отдельно перемножение матриц). Разбираться в коде в текущем его виде весьма проблематично.

Comment: ок, как это сделать с нуля в теории хотя бы?

Comment: Выше уже написал - разделить, протестировать, применить.

Comment: Протестировал, разделил - не верно расчитывается верхний угол камеры(вектор) и правый угол камеры (вектор), как нужно делать расчет(формула)?

Comment: Приведите код расчета *углов камеры* (звучит неверно, т.к. матрица камеры задается несколько иначе, не углами ..)

Comment: Выше уже написал.

Answer (score 1):

Откуда вы взяли свою формулу?
Обычно матрица направленной камеры (LookAt camera) задается вот так:

```
zaxis = normal(cameraTarget - cameraPosition)
xaxis = normal(cross(cameraUpVector, zaxis))
yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

 xaxis.x           yaxis.x           zaxis.x          0
 xaxis.y           yaxis.y           zaxis.y          0
 xaxis.z           yaxis.z           zaxis.z          0
-dot(xaxis, cameraPosition)  -dot(yaxis, cameraPosition)  -dot(zaxis, cameraPosition)  1
```

Обратите внимание на ориентацию рядов/столбцов, она у вас может быть другой.

Comment: из книги Франка луны, я знаю что матрица камеры вычисляется двумя строчками методами : LookAtLH как то так называется и установкой матрицы виды на самом инициализированном девайсе, но код который я привел, а точнее не я а Франк Луна в своей книге, более подробно описывает какими параметрами заполнена видовая матрица и как в ней располагаются данные

Comment: "вычисляется двумя строчками методами" .. ?